# How do I optimize a ForEach loop of views in a ZStack and reset when looped through?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a `ForEach` loop contained inside of a `ZStack`. The idea is to build a "Tinder-Like" interface. I have an issue where I might render 20-50 `Cards` which is a major strain on the system. It results in lagginess. If I render only 5, then it's much more responsive, however I do not know the proper structure to do this. I also need to be sure that I can "Re-loop" through the cards after the last one has been reached. This is what my struct looks like.

```
ZStack {
    //MARK: - Card View
    ForEach(googleApi.places) { place in
        CardView(card: Card(isFavorite: false, place: place), homeModel: homeViewModel)
    }
}.padding(.bottom)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no `LazyZStack` yet

Comment: But maybe `LazyVStack` + offset?

Comment: @aheze unfortunately that doesn't work. The view is still "On Screen" despite being in a LazyVStack, thus it does the same thing as the ZStack and causes lagginess until the cards are -5 or so. Mind you that's on a simulator, so a real device will be faster, but I want to knock it out while I am working in this area.